# Split JSON "dictonary" into separate rows

Tags: split, mariadb, mysql-json, mariadb-10.4

colleagues.
I have a table like this:

| id | param1 | param2 | config |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 789 | `{"confToUse": "b", "configs": {"a": { "qwe": "rty" }, "b": { "asd", "fgh" } } }` |

Small explanation: configurations live in a json 'dictionary' property `configs`, `configToUse` property points on config with this key to use.

My goal is to get new table where each row is a separate configuration:

| id | name | config |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x_uniq | a | `{ "qwe": "rty" }` |
| y_uniq | b | `{ "asd", "fgh" }` |

Ideally the result looks like this:

| id | param1 | param2 | use | name | config | use_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x_uniq | 456 | 789 | b | a | `{ "qwe": "rty" }` | y_uniq? |
| y_uniq | 456 | 789 | b | b | `{ "asd", "fgh" }` | y_uniq? |

For mysql version reason I can't use JSON_TABBLE. Only JSON_EXTRACT or so.

At this point could only do this:

```sql
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(tbl.config, "$.configToUse"),
    JSON_EXTRACT(tbl.config, "$.configs") -- I think there has to be some SELECT
FROM 
    configs_table tbl
WHERE
    tbl.id = 123
;
```

and get:

| xxx | yyy |
| --- | --- |
| b | `{"a": { "qwe": "rty" }, "b": { "asd", "fgh" } }` |

Please, give me some way to move.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to store data in JSON, since it makes it so difficult to work with?

Comment: If you have a limitation based on MYSQL Version please specify in the question what version, give the lads a bit of a chance when it comes to attempting an answer

Comment: @BillKarwin, I can do nothing with this legacy, actually my migration must be a cure :)
@RiggsFolly, oups... `10.4.20-MariaDB-1` (feel myself a donkey)

Comment: Is a config always composed of two properties? Are they always `a` and `b`?

Comment: @MatBailie, actually config have about 10-15 string keys(properties) that can be 'someKeyA', 'anotherKeyB', 'oneMoreKeyC`, but this list is known for me, 'a', 'b' is just for shorten. 'confToUse' always points to one of the keys(properties) in configs dictionary/object.

Comment: @MatBailie, no, actually there can be `1 to maxint` configs per record, but I saw not more 5 per record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need another table (or subquery) that has integers from 0 to *N*, where *N* is the greatest number of configs you might have.

Either create a utility table for these integers:

```
CREATE TABLE N ( N INT PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO N (N) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

Or else generate the table on demand as a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS N
...
```

With this, you can do a cross join to get each respective config key in your JSON document.

Here's a demo:

```
SELECT
  t.param1, t.param2,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(t.config, '$.confToUse')) AS `use`,
  t.name,
  JSON_EXTRACT(t.config, CONCAT('$.configs.', t.name)) AS config
FROM (
  SELECT c.param1, c.param2, c.config,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(c.config->'$.configs'), CONCAT('$[',N.N,']'))) AS name
  FROM N CROSS JOIN configs_table c
) AS t
WHERE t.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+------+------+----------------+
| param1 | param2 | use  | name | config         |
+--------+--------+------+------+----------------+
|    456 |    789 | b    | a    | {"qwe": "rty"} |
|    456 |    789 | b    | b    | {"asd": "fgh"} |
+--------+--------+------+------+----------------+
```

I can't tell from your question how you get the values `x_uniq` and `y_uniq`, so I'll leave that part of the solution to you.

If you think this solution is complex and difficult, let it serve as an example why using JSON in MySQL leads to a lot of trouble and time-consuming work. It is not convenient or correct to implement a pseudo-database on top of a database. This is sometimes called the [Inner-Platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) antipattern.

Comment: Thank you, Bill, your answeer is awesome and works for me as I expected! `x_uniq` and `y_uniq` are just newly generated keys, I'll use `UUID()` maybe. Now software gets row from config table, deserialize json from config column, reads `configToUse` prop and uses corresponding config like `a` or `b`, my goal is to add foreign key like `config_id` and then just join by it with newly created table (`old.config_id = new.id`).